# Opening Mootools SqueezeBox popup automatically on PageLoad

Tags: mootools, squeezebox

I am trying to get a SqueezeBox pop up to open automatically when a page is opened but the code I'm using opens the popup but the popup contents arent loaded.

I'm not that familiar thus I need some assistance as to what I'm doing wrong

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){ 
    var feedback = new Element('a', {
    'href': "gSlide/index.html",
    'rel' : "{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 400, y: 400}}"
    });

    SqueezeBox.fromElement(feedback);

});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SqueezeBox** have an `open()` method that simple does what you need. There's no need to create a dummy `<a>` element and then attach SqueezeBox on it.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() { 

   SqueezeBox.open("gSlide/index.html", {
       handler: 'iframe', 
       size: { x: 400, y: 400 }
   });

});
```

*Reference: http://digitarald.de/project/squeezebox/#how-to*